# Dynamic condition symbol in "if"

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I want to create a dynamic condition. It will look like

```
Model.send("attr_name") > 0 ? true : false
```

But how can I write symbol ">" dynamically ?

Comment: If the condition is coming from the user, be sure to whitelist what they can do, else they'll be able to run arbitrary methods on your objects.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall they will be in select tags, but thanks :).

Comment: Your `? true : false` is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did not quite understand what your question is, but this might be the answer:

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > s = "<"
 => "<" 
1.9.3p194 :005 > 0.send :"#{s}", 1
 => true
```

Comment: Thanks, it's right. Is there any other possability like this to do what i want?

Comment: Why not simply `0.send :<, 1` ?

Comment: @padde 'cause I have symbols "<" and others as a variables to make a dynamic condition.

Comment: or, more explictly: `0.send(s.to_sym, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the ternary operator `? :` . It can simply be written as:

```
Model.send("attr_name").send(condition,0)
```